# jQuery and Wordpress Plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

So I'm working on a plugin, but I'm having difficulties adding a jQuery function to it. I read other post and searched everywhere, but nothing seems to work. I see the jQuery in the header so I know that it's loading, but when I try to call the function nothing happens.

Here's what I have

```
function OneEightyView($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag){
shortcode_atts(array(
    'img1' => 'default var1',
    'img2' => false,
    'img3' => false,
    'img4' => false,
    'img5' => false
), $atts);

$img1 = $atts['img1'];
$img2 = $atts['img2'];
$img3 = $atts['img3'];
$img4 = $atts['img4'];
$img5 = $atts['img5'];

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#oeContianer').serce();
});
</script>

<div id ="oeContianer" >
    <img src="<?php echo $img3; ?>" data-images="<?php echo $img1 . ',' . $img2 . ',' . $img3 . ',' . $img4 . ',' . $img5 ?>" alt=""/>
</div>    
<?php   
}

function oneeighty_enqueue_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'selector_oneeighty_jquery_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'lib/jquery-2.1.3.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.8.1', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'selector_oneeighty_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jquery.serce.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.8.1', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'oneeighty_enqueue_script');

/**** Add Shortcode ****/
add_shortcode('one-eighty-wiew', 'OneEightyView');
```

One can replace those image "$atts" with any image url to see it in live action.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Check errors in browser console. probably see `$ is undefined` due to wordpress typically using `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Various ways , see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem which was cause by an extra jQuery file and not having the correct method of handling the functions. It was basically a jQuery conflict.

So what I did was switch "$" to jQuery and removed this line

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'selector_oneeighty_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ) . 'jquery.serce.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.8.1', true );
```

My new snippets look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#oeContianer').serce();
    });
</script>
<?php
function oneeighty_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'selector_oneeighty_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ) . 'jquery.serce.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.8.1', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'oneeighty_enqueue_script');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better not re-include jQuery main files cause conflict if re-include. You can remove this line and include default WordPress jQuery file. Your function will become:

```
function oneeighty_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'selector_oneeighty_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jquery.serce.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.8.1', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'oneeighty_enqueue_script');
```

If it still not work, open Console tab on Chrome Dev Tools to see if any error occur.

Comment: Or if you want to ensure jQuery loaded to run your plugin. Just add `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`. I will update my answer to clarify it.

Comment: Thank you, but it still wont work. I'll update my question with the full script soon

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your jQuery script. Note the `$` in the function parenthesis.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //now you can use the $
  $("#someId").val();

});
```

Also, you need to register your script before enqueueing it.

```
wp_register_script('selector_oneeighty_script',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jquery.serce.min.js');
```

Comment: I updated it to this but still wouldn't work jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#oeContianer').serce();
    });

Comment: What is `secre()` ?

Comment: It's a function which works will. This scrip works fine, but when I try to add it to wordpress it wont work.

Comment: does the script work when you use 'jQuery("#someId").val();' ?

Comment: The the problem is with the inclusion of your script. Are you use the file permissions are set properly on the script? Is the path correct?

Comment: Yes, everything is correct and so is the file path. When i add the script to the header manually they are duplicated and it begins to work, but then everything else does not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to register your script first.

Comment: So do i register it first and then enque it?

Comment: Yes. Also, your jquery is already registered, so don't worry about that.

Comment: If this works out, please be sure to mark the answer as solved.

Comment: It's still not working, but I'll give it another try when I get home and will upload the whole plugin to github. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

@galfaro if the function you want to use is this:

```
function OneEightyView($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag){
shortcode_atts(array(
    'img1' => 'default var1',
    'img2' => false,
    'img3' => false,
    'img4' => false,
    'img5' => false
), $atts);
```

shouldn't you call it like this?

```
$(function(){
    $('#oeContianer').OneEightyView();
});
```